# Search for a list from a list of lists and return the results

Tags: python, list

I have something like this

```py
lists = [ [1,2,3] , [4,5,6] , [8,9,10] ]
```

and I would like to be able to search for a element of a list and return the entirety of the list

```
search = 5
result = [4,5,6]
```

(doesn't have to be that exact format but I would like to be able to see all the elements from the list)

I've looked at other forums and when they search I only returns a true or false value, so I'm not sure if what I would like to do is even possible

Answer (score 2):

You can abuse the `next` function to get the first element of a iterable that matches a predicate like this:

```py
next(i for i in iterable if p(i))
```

If no element exists this will throw a `StopIteration` exception that you can optionally catch.

You can also use the `in`  operator to find if a element is in a list:

```py
5 in [1,2,3]
# False
5 in [4,5,6]
# True
```

Combining the two:

```py
next(l for l in lists if 5 in l)
```

Comment: Interesting.  User will need to catch the `StopIteration` error if the search subject is not found. (Upvoted because I learned something new!).

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy

```
a = np.array(lists)
out = a[np.where(a==5, True, False).any(1)].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation, I would create a function that will iterate the list and use the `in` operator to see if the value is in the list or not and finally return the index number of that value x or return False.

```
def result(srch, list):
    for x in list:
        if srch in x:
            return list[list.index(x)]
    return False


lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [8, 9, 10]]

search = 15

print(result(search, lists))
```

Result:

```
[4, 5, 6]
```